# Insert images from excel to word through table

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word, word-template

I need to call a word file from excel, and to create a template. Template will have 3 images UpperLeft, Upper Right and central image.

I thought that would be the best result do it through the table.

From some reason I can't create table from excel..

```
Private Sub CommandButton13_Click()   
    'Using early binding, not late-binding
    Dim wsDoc As Word.Document
    Dim wsApp As Word.Application
    Dim wsRng As Word.Range
    Dim wsTable as Word.Table

    Dim intNoOfRows
    Dim intNoOfColumns

    Dim s As Word.InlineShape
    Dim shp As Word.Shape

    intNoOfRows = 4
    intNoOfColumns = 2

    Set wsApp = New Word.Application
    wsApp.Visible = True

    Set wsDoc = wsApp.Documents.Add
    Set wsRange = wsDoc.Content

    Set wsTable = wsDoc.Tables.Add(wsRange, intNoOfRows, intNoOfColumns)
    wsTable.Borders.Enable = True
    wsTable.Cell(1, 1).Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture _
                       UserForm1.txtImageLogoAdecco
    wsTable.Cell(1, 2).Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphRight
    wsTable.Cell(1, 2).Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture _
                       UserForm1.txtImageLogoClient
    Set wsRng = wsTable.Cell(2, 1).Range
    With wsRng.Paragraphs.Add

    wsTable.Cell(2, 1).Merge MergeTo:=wsTable.Cell(2, 2)
    wsTable.Cell(2, 1).Height = 520
    wsTable.Cell(2, 1).Range.Paragraphs.Add
    wsTable.Cell(3, 1).Merge MergeTo:=objTable.Cell(3, 2)
    wsTable.Cell(3, 1).Range.Text = "Prepared by:" & "  " & UserForm1.txtPrepared
    wsTable.Cell(4, 1).Merge MergeTo:=objTable.Cell(4, 2)
    wsTable.Cell(4, 1).Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphRight
    wsTable.Cell(4, 1).Range.Text = "Belgrade," & " " & Format(Date, "MMMM DD, YYYY ")

    Set wsRange = Nothing
    Set wsTable = Nothing
    Set wsDoc = Nothing
    Set wsApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Why you prefer vba approach when an excel table containing 3 pictures can be easily pasted into word document.

Comment: Your problem description and your code don't match so it's a bit difficult to follow what you expect vs. what's probably happening... 1) If you don't want to save changes to template.docm use Documents.Add not Documents.Open. 2) Remove the With...End With around this statement. 3) Are the bookmarks already present in the document? I get the impression you want them in the table, yet you're inserting the table. Should you be targeting cells in the table, instead?

Comment: @CindyMeister exactly. Please, refer to my new updated code. I've managed to insert all pictures in table (to keep formatting where I want them), with background image I want to convert it to shape. I want to send iy behind the text, and finally I want to move cursor a few lines down and to write some text. I hope that its now is much clearer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's a bit clearer, but not completely. I've taken the liberty of editing your code so that it's correct, consistent and *readable* (without all the empty lines)!

I'll start with the part that is clear: << I want to move cursor a few lines down and to write some text. >>

To move the focus below a table, you get the table's range, then collapse it. For example:

Set wsRange = wsTable.Range
wsRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd 
'Now the range is in the paragraph following the table
wsRange.Text = "text following table"

"with background image I want to convert it to shape. I want to send iy behind the text"

This is the part that's not clear to me. Are you saying you want to insert one more image and position it behind the text? Use the Shapes.Add method and set the WrapFormat.Type to wdWrapBehind